# Problems inferring type with typescript

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I have a TypeScript function which removes a "path" in a Firebase database. It return a Promise which then resolves to a boolean flag indicating whether content was actually there in the first place (aka, no need to delete if it doesn't exist).

The function looks like this:

```
export function remove(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return exists(path)
    .then(existance => {
      return existance
        ? getRef(path).remove()
          .then(() => Promise.resolve(true))
        : Promise.resolve(false);
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(`There was an error trying to remove the path "${path}": `, err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

This, however, leads to the error messages below (note the difference in message is based on where in the expression i'm hovering):

[image]

If anyone's interested in the `exists()` function -- which, btw, has no problems with TypeScript -- it is:

```
export function exists(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return getRecord(path)
    .then(snap => snap.val()
      ? Promise.resolve(true)
      : Promise.resolve(false)
    )
    .catch(Promise.reject);
}
```

Anyway, i'm at a loss as to why I'm getting these errors and would love any insight anyone may have.

> p.s. i'm using TypeScript 2.2.2

---

UPDATE: as has been pointed out in the comments ... these errors appear to only occur when using the popular Bluebird promise library

Comment: Using standard built in promises, I don't get any errors for your code. That said, you are making this harder on yourself than you need. `() => Promise.resolve(true)` in this case is equivalent to `() => true`, there's no need to wrap your return values (or errors) in promises. Same thing for your exists function, `return getRecord(path).then(snap => Boolean(snap.val()))`, there's no need to catch with Promise.reject as the callback as that's essentially a noOP.

Comment: I _thought_ i needed the Promise.resolve/reject in order to allow users of the function the ability to continue the promise chain. That might not be true, been meaning to check an assumption of mine WRT to promises for a while, but even just return boolean values has no impact on the error.

Comment: FYI ... I use the popular bluebird promise library rather than the built-in promises (probably clear from above pictures).

Comment: I did just try it now and it is clearly related to something specific to Bluebird's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently are less than intuitive ways to get Bluebird promises to override the global Promise that TypeScript provides. The issue is discussed here:

- [DefinitelyTyped Issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10801)
- [This one is probably more informative actually](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/10831)

So in short, my problems were more the impact of using Bluebird Promises in *some* cases but native Promises in others. To force the use of Bluebird a working solution is to:

/src/[xxxx].js

```
import * as Bluebird from './bluebird';
```

/src/bluebird.js

```
declare module 'bluebird-global' {
  import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
  global { export interface Promise<T> extends Bluebird<T> {} }
}
```

In this way you should **always** get Bluebird promises and the error I ran into will be avoided.

---

Update ... even better solution. Include the `@types/bluebird-global` module and you're done!

> Note: if in your `tsconfig.js` file you're using the "types" parameter (most do not) then add *bluebird-global* to the section:

```
types: [
  "bluebird-global"
]
```

Comment: Hi @ken. Could you update your `update`, please? :) 1. It's `@types/bluebird-global`, not `@types/global-bluebird` (you almost gave me a heart attack, because I thought someone had the bright idea of fragmenting this space even further). 2. Devs don't need to define `compilerOptions.types` unless they already use `compilerOptions.types` (this is rare imo, so it's safe to assume devs don't need to do that at all, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b036cb2/types/bluebird-global/index.d.ts#L14). In case you're wondering: the instructions were changed yesterday :)

Comment: Updating now :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Too much callback hell. Try to use modern javascript:

```
export async function remove(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        const e: boolean = await exists(path);
        if (e) {
            await getRef(path).remove();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`There was an error trying to remove the path "${path}": `, err);
        throw err;
    } 
}
```

I don't see any reason why it should not work. But in case - post a comment.

Comment: I like async/await too but we're not using it on this project yet. Your answer, however, doesn't seem to address the question at hand which is related to TypeScript errors.